# ActiveAdmin set up for resource, but won't create new item through custom form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have ActiveAdmin setup in my rails application version 3.2 where I have a BlogPost model set up perfectly fine so I can view index without an issue.

But when I create a new blogpost like

```
ActiveAdmin.register BlogPost do


  index do
    column :title do |post|
      link_to post.title, blog_post_path(post)
    end
    column :body
    column :created_at
    column :image_url
    default_actions
  end

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Blog Post" do
      f.input :title
      f.input :body, as: :html_editor
      f.input :image_url
    end
    f.actions
  end

end
```

It does nothing and doesn't actually create a new post, nor throw an error. It just refreshes the page. I'm also using default resources, so that my blog_post_controller inherits from ApplicationController instead of InheritedResources.

What could be the cause of the issue, or what more do I need to configure for activeadmin to hit the create route through post on my blog_post_controller?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was validating for another field that I wasn't sending in the post request, and subsequently was failing silently.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this same issue and the problem was that I was validating presence of a foreign key on child associations...but the parent object hadn't yet been created so there was no ID present to validate.

Solved this problem by adding `:inverse_of => :parent_model_name` to the association on the parent model and updating validation on the child models to `validates :parent_model_name, :presence => true` instead of `validates :parent_object_id`

Here's a good resource - https://robots.thoughtbot.com/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-has-many-through

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a bit more? I'm having the same issue as you. I have a validate_presence_of :something in my join table for an association and that's creating the error when I try to create a new object.

Comment: @JCC if you're validating the presence of an attribute on an associated object before the parent is created, that is what's raising the error.  It won't validate/let you create the object(s) unless you add the `inverse_of` bit to your models.

Comment: Yes, I finally figured it out. Thanks to your hints.